# How to sort by formatted date with Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have the following:

```
Name      Date
-----   -------------------
Alice   2013-02-10 15:17:00
Alice   2013-02-10 16:19:00
Alice   2013-02-10 17:21:00
Bob     2013-02-10 18:23:00
Alice   2013-02-10 19:25:00
```

This is what happens when I sort for date, then for name. It considers the hours first. What I really want is this:

```
Name      Date
-----   -------------------
Alice   2013-02-10 15:17:00
Alice   2013-02-10 16:19:00
Alice   2013-02-10 17:21:00
Alice   2013-02-10 19:25:00
Bob     2013-02-10 18:23:00
```

So, I want to sort first by `%Y-%m-%d`, then by name.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can use a sort _script for that:

```
"sort": {
"_script": {
  "script": "new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(new Date(doc['date'].value))",
  "type": "string",
  "order": "desc"
},
"name": "asc"
```

**Be aware that this is a security flaw**. Read more at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: are you dates indexed as date types?

Answer (score 0):

You might use ".keyword".

When we use below code, where **added_on** is date, what happens !! [attribute text is analyzed, meaning it is broken up into distinct words when stored, and allows for free-text searches on one or more words in the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869795/difference-between-a-field-and-the-field-keyword)

so there is "text" and "keyword" associated with fields, so if we need to use aggregation in the query, we need the field value in general the keyword.

```
BEFORE

"_source":{....}
"query" : {...}
"sort": [
{
  "added_on": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
]

AFTER
"_source":{....}
"query" : {...}
"sort": [
{
  "added_on.keyword": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
]
```