# difference between a field and the field.keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

If I add a document with several fields to an Elasticsearch index, when I view it in Kibana, I get each time the same field twice. One of them will be called

```
some_field
```

and the other one will be called

```
some_field.keyword
```

Where does this behaviour come from and what is the difference between both of them?

PS: one of them is aggregatable (not sure what that means) and the other (without keyword) is not.

Answer (score 88):

***Update :*** A short answer would be that type: text is analyzed, meaning it is broken up into distinct words when stored, and allows for free-text searches on one or more words in the field. The .keyword field takes the same input and keeps as one large string, meaning it can be aggregated on, and you can use wildcard searches on it. Aggregatable means you can use it in aggregations in elasticsearch, which resembles a sql group by if you are familiar with that. In Kibana you would probably use the .keyword field with aggregations to count distinct values etc.

---

Please take a look on this article about [`text` vs. `keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings).

Briefly: since Elasticsearch 5.0 `string` type was replaced by `text` and `keyword` types. Since then when you do not specify explicit mapping, for simple document with string:

```
{
  "some_field": "string value"
}
```

below dynamic mapping will be created:

```
{
  "some_field": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> As a consequence, it will both be possible to perform full-text search on `some_field`, and keyword search and aggregations using the `some_field.keyword` field.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The linked article explains this, but a short answer would be that type: text is analyzed, meaning it is broken up into distinct words when stored, and allows for free-text searches on one or more words in the field. The .keyword field takes the same input and keeps as one large string, meaning it can be aggregated on, and you can use wildcard searches on it.
Aggregatable means you can use it in aggregations in elasticsearch, which resembles a sql group by if you are familiar with that. In Kibana you would probably use the .keyword field with aggregations to count distinct values etc.

Comment: @Peter, maybe you would like to prepare edit for my answer?

Comment: To search on multiple keywords, use   `"{query": { "bool": { "filter": [ { "term": { "your_field_name.keyword": "your_value" }}, { "term": { "your_field_name_2.keyword": "your_value_2" }} ]}}` for a single keyword, you can lose the `[]`. Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383259/308851 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html
}

Comment: And the `multi-field` is the mechanism that allows one field to be indexed in several ways: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: Resolved my issue. Thanks a lot for this answer.

Answer (score 9):

Look at [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12394) issue. There is some explanation of your question in it. Roughly speaking `some_field` is analyzed and can be used for fulltext search. On the other hand `some_field.keyword` is not analyzed and can be used in term queries or in aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer your questions one by one.
Where does this behavior come from?
It is introduced in Elastic 5.0.

What is the difference between the two?
some_field is used for full text search and some_field.keyword is used for keyword searching.
Full text searching is used when we want to include individual tokens of a field's value to be included in search. For instance, if you are searching for all the hotel names that has "farm" in it, such as hay farm house, Windy harbour farm house etc.

Keyword searching is used when we want to include the whole value of the field in search and not individual tokens from the value. For eg, suppose you are indexing documents based on city field. Aggregating based on this field will have separate count for "new" and "york" instead of "new york" which is usually the expected behavior.

From Elastic 5.0 onwards, strings now will be mapped both as keyword and text by default.

Comment: So from 5.0 there's no distinction between the two, to get you correctly?