# ElasticSearch: Restrict Aggregations to Query String

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I'm struggling to get my aggregations to be restricted to my query.
I, of course, tried:

```
{
    "_source": ["burger.id", "burger.user_name", "burger.timestamp"],
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "burger.user_name:Bob"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "burger_count": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "burger.id.keyword"
            }
        },
        "min_dtm": {
            "min": {
                "field": "burger.timestamp"
            }
        },
        "max_dtm": {
            "max": {
                "field": "burger.timestamp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am very set on using "query_string" for filtering, as we have a very nice front-end that allows users to easily build queries that are then turned into a "query_string."

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to combine query_string and aggregations so that the aggregations are only over the results of the query!

I've read through *many* SO posts about doing this, but they are all very old and outdated as they all suggest the deprecated way of Filtered Queries, but even that doesn't implement query_string.

**UPDATE**

Here are some example documents.
It appears that my results are not being filtered by my query. Is there a setting that I am missing?
I also changed all of the fields to be about burgers...

```
{
    "_index": "burgers",
    "_type": "burger",
    "_id": "123",
    "_score": 5.3759894,
    "_source": {
      "inference": {
        "id": "1",
        "user_name": "Jonathan",
        "timestamp": 1541521691847
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "burgers",
    "_type": "burger",
    "_id": "456",
    "_score": 5.3759894,
    "_source": {
      "inference": {
        "id": "2",
        "user_name": "Ryan",
        "timestamp": 1542416601153
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "burgers",
    "_type": "burger",
    "_id": "789",
    "_score": 5.3759894,
    "_source": {
      "inference": {
        "id": "3",
        "user_name": "Grant",
        "timestamp": 1542237715511
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your query is correct. This will get documents based on you query string and then all the aggregations will run the this set of documents.

Comment: @NishantSaini  The results are the same no matter what the query, and I have many users.

Comment: Can you add minimal and verifiable example where the issue can be replicated as I don't see any issue with the query. Also what the version of elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: Not sure what more I can provide, legally, but we are using 6.4.

Comment: Actually, maybe not. Let me check on that.

Comment: If you could add a few sample docs (2 or 3) against which if I run the above query, it gives the result which was not expected.

Comment: We have ES 5.1.1, Lucene 6.3.0. I could try to come up with some sample docs. I need to be very careful to not reveal any of our data.

Comment: I just noticed an issue in my result set. My results are not being filtered to `burger.user_name:Bob`. I got back multiple users. Is there a setting I am missing for "match all?"

Comment: @NishantSaini I've added the example documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer!
It appears that the issue was caused by querying the **text** field of `burger.user_name` instead of the **keyword** field: `burger.user_name.keyword`.
Changing my query_string to use the **keyword** for each text field solved my issue.

```
{
    "_source": ["burger.id", "burger.user_name", "burger.timestamp"],
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "burger.user_name.keyword:Bob"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "burger_count": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "burger.id.keyword"
            }
        },
        "min_dtm": {
            "min": {
                "field": "burger.timestamp"
            }
        },
        "max_dtm": {
            "max": {
                "field": "burger.timestamp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[**This SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869795/difference-between-a-field-and-the-field-keyword#answer-48875105) gives a great, brief explanation why.