# ElasticSearch Aggregarion - Group by count without analyzing field

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

We have a field category in our index , We want to get number of records for each category using aggregation query.

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genres" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "category" } 
        }
    }
}
```

We are getting results but it is giving results after analyzing category. Something like this

```
           {
                "key": "chil",
                "doc_count": 343503
            },
            {
                "key": "child",
                "doc_count": 343503
            },
            {
                "key": "childr",
                "doc_count": 343503
            },
            {
                "key": "childre",
                "doc_count": 343503
            },
```

**But I want results  without analyzing**, I hope it is possible, Can someone help me with the query.

Expected

```
            {
                "key": "children",
                "doc_count": 343503
            },
            {
                "key": "Category1",
                "doc_count": 43503
            },
            {
                "key": "Category2",
                "doc_count": 60000
            }
```

We are having autocomplete analyzer for the field categoryqu in mapping

```
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can aggregate on `keyword` text datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aggregating on `.keyword`. But from what it looks like, you haven't specified the keyword field in your mapping.

So adjust your mapping like this:

```
{
  "category":{
    "type":"text",

    "fields":{
      "keyword":{
        "type":"keyword",
        "ignore_above":256
      },

      "name":{
        "analyzer":"autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer":"standard",
        "type":"text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and run the following

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs":{
    "genres":{
      "terms":{
        "field":"category.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Performing search on `category` will use the ES-default text mapping. Using `category.name` will use the analyzer & search analyzer you specified. And searching/aggregating on `category.keyword` will perform the operation on the case-sensitive keyword -- exactly what you expect.

Comment: Do I need to add another field keyword under category , Do i need to pass this keyword when i ingest data ?  Something like  category { "keyword" : "CAT1", "name" : "Category 1" }

Comment: That's bad practice. If you want to have 2 different values for a field, rather create 2 separate fields. When you pass `{"name": "Category 1"}`, ES will index it once as a `text` and a second time as a `keyword` (provided you use the mapping from my answer). That's the point -- one value but 2 different indexing processes...
If you want to ingest a different variant of the value, use a separate field for it and make its `type` equal to `keyword`. That way you'll be able to search on it without using the `.keyword` notation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48875105/8160318 if it's still unclear.